# VLAN AND PHP VIRTUALBOX

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vlan, virtualbox

I have an ubuntu server with 2 network cards and I'm currently using only one network card.
In that server I have php-virtualbox installed. The server is connected to a switch port tagged for ALL vlans.
I have a virtual machine in the server with windows 10 as a guest and two virtual network cards.
I would like to have in this guest 1 network card untagged (and I actually have it) and the other one tagged for vlan 20.
Is there a setting in php-virtualbox or virtualbox that let me choose the vlan tag of the virtualized network cards?
Kindest Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Tag the (bridged) network interface from the guest operating system, it should work as expected.

If you want the guest OS to access a VLAN without actually tagging the interface from the guest, you should create a tagged adapter on the host, and bridge the virtual adapter to that interface (e.g. eth0.20).